# Create a simple form with Symfony

Tags: forms, controller, symfony-3.4

I'm getting crazy with a veeery simple thing! I just want to make a small form with one text input field and a validation button and get the value entered by the user. And it doesn't work. Absolutely crazy... I'm sure it's a very small thing, but I cannot solve it!

Here is my code:

```
<?php

namespace PublicBundle\Controller;

use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\SubmitType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\TextType;

/**
 * Description of AccountRecoveryController
 *
 */
class AccountRecoveryController extends Controller {

    /**
    * 
    * @Route("/account_recovery", name="account_recovery")
    */
    function accountRecoveryAction(Request $request){

        $form = $this->createFormBuilder()
            ->add('username', TextType::class, array(
                    'label' => 'Adresse e-mail', 
                    'attr'  => array('placeholder' => 'E-MAIL'),
                    'mapped' => false
                    ))
                ->add('submit', SubmitType::class, array(
                    'label' => 'Submit'
                    ))
            ->getForm();

        $form->handleRequest($request);

        if ($form->isSubmitted()){
            echo 'ok';
            $eMail = $form->get('username')->getData();
            echo $eMail;
        }

        return $this->render('accountRecoveryRequest.html.twig', array(
            'form' => $form->createView(),
        ));
    }  
}
```

The form is rendered and works. The "ok" is displayed after clicking on "Submit". Buuuut $eMail is always empty... Why??

Any idea?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You should also check if the form is valid in your if

```
if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()){
....
```

If it is not valid, you can check for errors with

```
$form->getErrors(true)
```

The profiler should also give you enough pointers as to why you have no data, for example invalid values etc.
And you can always use dump() to check what your values are at any point in your code.